# Filter Dataframe based on Reference Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reference

I have 3 tables whereby I need to have an end result of a combination  of the currency values for different portfolios.
Dataframe 1: A Reference table containing only the portfolios we care about and the thresholds

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Portfolio': ['Port1', 'Port2', 'Port3'], 
                   'PosThresh': [0.0055, 0.0055, 0.0055],
                   'NegThresh': [-0.0055, -0.0055, -0.0055]})
```

| Portfolio | PosThresh | NegThresh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Port1 | 0.0055 | -0.0055 |
| Port2 | 0.0055 | -0.0055 |
| Port3 | 0.0055 | -0.0055 |

Dataframe 2: The currency values contained within the Groups (There will be more than 1 currency for each portfolio)

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Portfolio': ['Port1', 'Port2', 'Port2', 'Port2', 
                   'Port3', 'Port3', 'Port4', 'Port4'], 
                   'Value': [0.1, 0.003, 0.2, 0.004, 0.2, 0.65, 0.23, 
                    0.004],
                   'Currency': ['EUR', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'USD', 'USD', 'CHF', 
                   'CNY', 'EUR']})
```

| Portfolio | Value | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Port1 | 0.1 | EUR |
| Port1 | 0.05 | CHF |
| Port1 | 0.1 | CNY |
| Port2 | -0.05 | USD |
| Port2 | -0.1 | EUR |
| Port2 | 0.05 | CHF |
| Port3 | 0.5 | CNY |
| Port3 | 0.2 | CHF |
| Port4 | 0.5 | EUR |
| Port4 | 0.005 | CNY |
| Port4 | 0.003 | CHF |

Dataframe 3: The main portfolio data where we need to report on any currencies outside of the threshold stored within the reference table.

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Portfolio': ['Port1', 'Port2', 'Port3'], 
                   'Value': [0.05, -0.003, 0.004]})
```

| Portfolio | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Port1 | 0.05 |
| Port2 | -0.003 |
| Port3 | 0.004 |

I need to complete the following:

1. Filter df2 against df1 to find only the portfolios we care about
2. Combine the CHF & CNY values for each portfolio to give a total value (All other currencies are left as they are)
3. Flag currencies in df2 which fall outside of the Portfolio PosThresh & NegThresh columns from df1
4. Flag df3 Values which fall outside the thresholds
5. Report on each portfolio we checked to give an output

Expected Outcome:

| Portfolio | Value | Outside Threshold? | Currencies Outside Thresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Port1 | 0.1 | Yes | EUR (0.1), CHF/CNY (0.2) |
| Port2 | -0.05 | Yes | USD (-0.05) |

I hope that all makes sense...

Comment: You should provide code to [reproduce all the DataFrames easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @mozwayI have updated with code to recreate the tables. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your expected output is however unclear, is it complete? Also how is portfolio 2 outside of threshold? You want a lot of steps but many of them are unclear. Please provide your own attempt